# Is it possible to set Piwik's Do-Not-Track feature per Website and not globally?

Tags: configuration, matomo

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) is a great open source web analytics platform website owners can use to track their visitors without giving their visitor's data to google, facebook etc.

Piwik supports tracking of multiple websites in one installation.

Piwik has a [Do-not-Track](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track) (DNT) [feature](http://piwik.org/docs/privacy/#step-4-respect-donottrack-preference), that allows to skip visitor tracking when DNT is activated in the browser.

Unfortunately my impression is that I have to activate that DNT feature either globally for all tracked websites of that Piwik installation or disable it completely.

Am I right?
Is there a way/workaround to bypass that limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option with current Piwik versions as a JavaScript Tracking Configuration:

```
setDoNotTrack( bool )
```

The full Tracker option:

```
_paq.push(['setDoNotTrack', true]);
```

So you can easily add it per-page to the tracker code to switch it on and off depending on the visited page.

See http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-javascript for more information.

Comment: One could use this in a custom browser script to reliably deactivate piwik on all visited pages. But personally I like piwik and even deactivated the corresponding rule in AdBlock because I wan't to honour those who are not using Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such option in Piwik. And a quick search in Piwik and its database did not show any way to configure DNT per site.

If it is sufficient for your situation, the opt-out button migth help you http://piwik.org/docs/privacy/#step-3-include-a-web-analytics-opt-out-feature-on-your-site-using-an-iframe

Or you could of course run two Piwik instances. One for DNT-sites and one for the others.